# Samsung Galaxy Fit firmware update fails

Tags: updates, samsung-kies, device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-fit

I have a Samsung Galaxy Fit, model GT-S5670B.

When i connect the phone to the pc, Samsung Kies (version 2.5.3.13043_14) identifies that there is a firmware update available.

I agree to do the upgrade and follow the instructions which basically are not turning off nor disconnecting the device and wait. At some point, after downloading the firmware files i believe, the update just throws an unexpected error and stops. I have the option of trying and restoring my device and thats it!

There is no feedback nor message whatsoever about what the error was and why it happened. And also, even if i don't restore my device and just reboot it, it is okay as if nothing had happened so i believe that the installation of the firmware didn't event begun.

Anyone knows how i can upgrade my Galaxy Fit from Android version 2.2.1 to 2.3.6? Or what the problem with Samsung Kies is?

Already tried to uninstall and reinstall Samsung Kies but nothing changed.

Thanks in advance!